# maven - where to store external jar files if needed

Tags: java, maven, jar

What is the convention to store jar files inside maven project? I know that I should download jars using maven itself, but this time the case is different. I'm doing a course (coursera.org) and I've got somewhat secret jar file which I'm supposed to use and it's not public - I won't download it with maven. And I do want to store the .jar file in my private repo (bitbucket). The question is just where should I put the file, so that maven project will be able to use this jar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add it to local repository. And then use it as any other jar.

You do it like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={filename}.jar -DgroupId={some.group.id} 
-DartifactId={artifact} -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then you use it like this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>{some.group.id}</groupId>
      <artifactId>{artifact} </artifactId>
      <version>{version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: ok, but where exactly shall I put it? Is `src/main/resources` ok?

Comment: when you use maven you don't put jar files somewhere in your project. everything you need to do is declare dependency. then your project uses jar files from local repository. they are downloaded usually but in this case you put it in explicitly with maven install. then you just add dependency and you are done.

Comment: if you want to set it up on another pc it is ok to put it where ever you like and create script that will add it to local repository on new pc.

Comment: adding the dependency only to your local repository will end with other people not being able to build the project as they don't have this dependency. Better use a repository manager as suggested by @khmarbaise

Comment: yes for someone with their own server but this is for course on coursera.org and probably one user. where to install repository manager in this case and how will other users access it. with script for adding jar to local repository everything will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple way to do this:
Create a file based maven repo inside the project directory

**Pros:**
- Anyone can checkout the project and do a maven compile
- No need to install a repository manager

**Cons:**
 - The jar will be in project directory

**How to do this?**
I am including ojdbc6.jar in a project.

**Step 1:**
Copy the ojdbc6.jar to ${project.baseDir}/lib/com/oracle/driver/ojdbc6/SNAPSHOT/ojdbc6-SNAPSHOT.jar

**Step 2:**
Add the dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step 3:**
Add this to your pom. **Here we are asking maven to consider the lib directory
inside your project dir as a maven repo.**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <name>mycustom repo</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
     </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Step 4:**
Analyse the path of the jar file in step 2. 
${project.baseDir}/lib/com/oracle/driver/ojdbc6/SNAPSHOT/ojdbc6-SNAPSHOT.jar

- com/oracle/driver/ -- groupId (must be 3 components)
- ojdbc6/ -- artifactId
- SNAPSHOT/ -- verison

We have stored the jar, very similar to how maven stores in a repo.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing is to [install a repository manager](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) like Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva and store such files into the repository manager and use them as usual dependency.